# I want to Convert array into Custom Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have array of Strings like this:
**let arr = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JAVASCRIPT']**

I have converted this array into an object using {...arr} method and the result is:
**{
0: "HTML",
1: "CSS",
2: "JAVASCRIPT"
}**
I want this result in this format because I am using Fluent UI react dropdown and there inside options, we have arrays of objects having their own key and text. But I did not understand How do I customize my object like this -->

```
[
 {key: "HTML", text: "HTML"},
 { key: "CSS", text: "CSS" },
 { key: "JAVASCRIPT", text: "JAVASCRIPT" }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's `Array.map()` method is meant for a task like this. See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for details.

Below is an example solution for your needs.

```js
const arr = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JAVASCRIPT'];

const obj = arr.map(item => {
  return { key: item, text: item}
});

console.log(obj);
```